# How should I connect to webservice using username, password and signature in PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, authorization, nusoap, soap-client

I need to connect to a particular webservice. I've been provided with WS's address, username, password and signature. However I don't know where and how provide these credentials to be able to use webservice functions.

I'll be very grateful for some code samples using SoapClient or nuSOAP showing how to achieve proper authorization.

The link for webservice is [here](https://net.eurotax.pl/etgplws/ETGPLService.asmx)

Comment: You're much more likely to get responses if you show that you've at least attempted the problem. Post some code that you've tried and are having trouble with and someone will be able to help you out with that.

Comment: Your question is equivalent to 'Gimme teh codez plz?'. Show what you achieved so far.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read manual? There are some examples with wsdl file, user and password:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php